# What is the purpose of the co node.js library?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, generator

I am new to node.js and am working on a code base, which is making use of the co library by wrapping calls to generator functions. A simplified example looks like this:

```
module.exports.gatherData = function*()
{
  // let img = //get the 1 pixel image from somewhere
  // this.type = "image/gif";
  // this.body = img;

  co(saveData(this.query));
  return;
```

};

```
function *saveData(query)
{   
  if(query.sid && query.url)
  {
      // save the data
  }
}
```

So I went to the co home page on github and the description says:

"Generator based control flow goodness for nodejs and the browser, using promises, letting you write non-blocking code in a nice-ish way."

Wouldn't this code be non-blocking too in the context of node.js?

```
yield saveData(this.query)
```

Comment: *Wouldn't this code be non-blocking too in the context of node.js?* No. Iterators & generators are synchronous operations. The *co* library uses the generator syntax to wrap promises to make asyncronous code look like it's written in a synchronous manner. `yield saveData` would simply yield an unresolved Promise

Comment: Actually `co(saveData(this.query));` inside a generator is rubbish indeed.

Comment: Why rubbish? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing blocking/non-blocking about generator functions. They're just a tool to express interruptible control flow.

How the flow is interrupted is only determined by the caller of the generator, in this case the `co` library which does wait for asynchronous values when they are yielded. There are many ways to skin this cat with `co`:

- ```
  module.exports.gatherData = co.coroutine(function*() {
    …
    yield saveData(this.query));
  });
  var saveData = co.coroutine(function* (query) {   
    if(query.sid && query.url) {
        // save the data
    }
  });
  ```
- ```
  module.exports.gatherData = co.coroutine(function*() {
    …
    yield co(saveData(this.query));
  });
  function *saveData(query) {   
    if(query.sid && query.url) {
        // save the data
    }
  }
  ```
- ```
  module.exports.gatherData = co.coroutine(function*() {
    …
    yield* saveData(this.query));
  });
  function *saveData(query) {   
    if(query.sid && query.url) {
        // save the data
    }
  }
  ```